# Hibernate duplicate children array when selecting

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am having an issue with Hibernate and selecting rows that are related to other rows in the same table. I am getting the correct results but I am getting two arrays of the same data.

For example I get this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "Banner",
    "childCategories": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "category": "Flash Banner",
        "childCategories": [],
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "category": "Image Banner",
        "childCategories": [],
        "children": []
      }
    ],
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "category": "Flash Banner",
        "childCategories": [],
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "category": "Image Banner",
        "childCategories": [],
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I am expecting this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "Banner",
    "childCategories": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "category": "Flash Banner",
        "childCategories": [],
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "category": "Image Banner",
        "childCategories": [],
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is what is in my entity to set up the relationship to the parent row and add the results to the childCategories property.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "adMediaCategory")
public class AdMediaCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String category;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private AdMediaCategory parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<AdMediaCategory> childCategories = new HashSet<>();

    public Integer getId() {
    `enter code here`return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public AdMediaCategory getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public void setParent(AdMediaCategory parentCategory) {
        this.parent = parentCategory;
    }

    public Set<AdMediaCategory> getChildren() {
        return this.childCategories;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<AdMediaCategory> children) {
        this.childCategories = children;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see an issue with these annotations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add your getters/setters.

Comment: Done. I left them out because there were no annotations so didn't think it would be useful

Comment: Look at your annotations... You have a `getChildren` and a different field with an annotation. Now both fields and properties are going to be exported. Resulting in 2 elements in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Not sure I understand. I thought the annotations above my childCategories property would assign the value to that and the getter would return it that value and not get it again. Would you be able to give me some feedback on which annotations need to be changed please?

Comment: Don't worry. I changed the name of getChildren to getChildCategories and that worked. I was unaware that the function name of getChildren had that affect.